# Angular: displaying a profile Picture after retrieving User data from back-end

Tags: angular

So I load the component and on init I want to retrieve the user data (with the link to profile picture) from the back-end. Then I want to display this profile picture in my template.

I thought I would do this by putting the SRC attribute between brackets and linking it to a profilePic property of the component. I also added an ngIf to the img tag.

Unfortunately it does not show the profile this way. Could someone tell me why and how to fix this?

(there's no issue with the data I get back from the back-end)

**template**

```
<img *ngIf="profilePic" class="img__profile-picture" [src]="profilePic" alt="profile-pic">
```

**Component**

```
export class ProfileNavComponent implements OnInit {

    fileToUpload: File = null;
    profilePic = null;

    constructor(private userService: UserService, private authService: AuthenticationService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.getUserData()
    }

    getUserData(){
        if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
            let userId = this.authService.currentUser().user._id;

            this.userService.getUserData(userId)
                .subscribe( data => {
                    if (data.obj.profilePicture.uploaded){

                        this.profilePic = '../../images/profile-pictures/' + data.obj.profilePicture.name;
                    }
                })
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: screenshot of dev tools. path contains the path to the image, but it doesn't show the image.**

[image]

**Edit 2: network tab in dev tools**

[image]

Edit 3: this is my project structure. I tried every road from `'assets/app/images/profile-pictures/' + data.obj.profilePicture.name;` til `profile-pictures/' + data.obj.profilePicture.name;`. None of them work and show the picture.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems ok, most probably the path does not resolve, are you getting 404? Try absolute path.

Comment: I don't get any errors. The weird thing is if I add the picture path manually at the SRC attribute without the brackets, it shows the image. It's just when I do it in the above way it doesn't seem to work. I checked the dev tools and the src attribute does however seems to contain  the path I had intended (I  edited original post to show screenshot), it just doesn't show the image.

Comment: And what would the general path look like in this case?

Comment: That depends on your config. Still, check network tab in dev tools for img request.

Comment: Ok, I added a screenshot of the network tab to the original post.

Comment: code looks ok to me. The only two suspect is 1. css on your image, 2. the `../../` relevant path in your code.

Comment: I've only added absolute positioning to the image so it has to be the path.

Comment: @tilly I must admit, I don't know... It really seems OK to me. Sorry about that.

Comment: I strongly recommend using an absolute path to your images rather than a relative one. Relative image paths are relative to the URL, not the component, and that URL may have different sub-domains in production/other servers. As @Chybie has said, you should update the path to be absolute. If you have `src/assets/images/...` then your path should be `assets/images/...`.

Comment: I have added my project structure to the original post. I have tried all the paths between the assets folder and my image folder, but none show me the image. Could it have something to do with my project structure? I'm using a MEAN stack app with Webstack and in the past I've had troubles with displaying images, but they seemed to have disappeared until yesterday I tried this.

Comment: I also tried to directly add the absolute paths into my src attribute, but unlike the relative path, none of the ones I tried (from assets/app/images/profile-pictures/name.png until profile-pictures/name.png) worked. I honestly have no clue what's wrong, but these images are quite vital to my project so I can't move on without them.